# what's the difference between use {{}} or not when use ng-show/hide

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

When I try to do the auto show/hide, i found that if I use {{}} in the attribute value expression, the DOM initial status is correct, but when i update the model, view hasn't been updated, the "ng-hide" class hasn't been added to the DOM even the attribute's value has been updated correctly as "false". The incorrect DOM looks like that:

```
    <p class="grey-text" ng-show="false">no data</p>
```

But if I don't use {{}}, the class can update correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The `ng-show` directive (and most directives, including custom directives) accepts an expression as a parameter.

The `{{ }}` operators are [Interpolation Markup](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation).  The expression *inside* the interpolation operators is evaluated, and text is output.  There is no guarantee that this interpolation will be completed before the directive has evaluated the data.

> •There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.

It is also redundant, since the directive is already designed to take the expression and perform interpolation on it before evaluating the result.  If interpolation were to happen before the directive, the result would be something like:

1. Interpolate `{{myVar}}` and return the result.
2. Write result `'false'` into the DOM.
3. Directive reads `'false'` from DOM.
4. Directive interpolates `'false'`, returning `false`.

Instead, you want a more natural flow:

1. Directive reads `myvar` from the DOM
2. Directive interpolates `myvar`, returning `false`.

Some further clarification:

All this interpolation and evaluation happens in a single `$digest` cycle.  Interpolating and updating the DOM does not change the value of the expression, merely how it is displayed.  Therefore, interpolation does not trigger `$watch` or a new `$digest`, and if a directive missed seeing the value in one form or another, they have no way of knowing.  Therefore, directives must accept the raw expression and perform interpolation themselves to guarantee accurate results.

Comment: I think the interpolate work flow is still in $apply, so the attribute value change will be watched, unless the attribute value hasn't been changed.

Comment: No, you misunderstand.  Interpolation is a directive, with a priority, and other directives with higher priority may check the value before it is updated and never know it changed.  The result is that you see the update in the DOM but the directive doesn't act on it.  For this reason, directives aren't designed to use the syntax.  The same applies to other directives like ngInit